# YAML config file is not loaded in dyanconf settings

Tags: python-3.x, configuration, yaml, config, pyyaml

Here is my project structure:

```
project/
   src/
      settings.py
   examples/
      example-config.yaml
```

```py
# settings.py
OUTPUT_DIR = "generated"
```

```yaml
# example-config.yaml
OUTPUT_DIR: "custom_dir"
```

According to the docs `settings.py` gets automatically loaded. Therefore the code below works:

```py
from dynaconf import settings
print(settings.OUTPUT_DIR) # prints -> generated
```

However when trying to load the `example-config.yaml`, nothing changes. See below:

```py
from dynaconf import settings
settings.load_file("../examples/example-config.yaml")
print(settings.OUTPUT_DIR) # prints -> generated. expected -> custom_dir
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly set the root directory for the import, I was facing a similar problem where the configuration file was not found, and dynaconf silently suppressed all errors.

For older Dynaconf you can set the `ROOT_PATH_FOR_DYNACONF` environment variable to the base path of the project.

For Dynaconf version > 3, the recommendation is to make an instance of Dynaconf yourself. You should set the `root_path` there.

config.py file:

```
from dynaconf import Dynaconf

settings = Dynaconf(root_path="/path/to/project")
```

Then you can use the relative import.

```
from project.config import settings

settings.load_file("examples/example-config.yaml")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well

```
OUTPUT_DIR = "custom_dir"
```

in YAML is one single scalar, not a dictionary. You want to use proper YAML syntax, which is

```yaml
OUTPUT_DIR: custom_dir
```

Comment: Actually it was a mistake in my question. The yaml file is actually correct. I fixed the error. The question still stands.

Comment: Also since dynaconf uses PyYaml, it detects the syntax issues. So I am sure there is no syntax issues in my file.